# MongoDB Realm has [error exchanging access code with OAuth2 provider]

Tags: java, android, mongodb, realm

I am currently creating a simple app with the purposes are:

- Sign In with Google through GoogleSignInSDK then get the `token` from google, and use that for `io.realm.mongodb.Credentials.google(token)`.
- But I always get the error `E/SignInActivity: AUTH_ERROR(realm::app::ServiceError:47): error exchanging access code with OAuth2 provider`.

I tried:

- Followed unclear guidelines from https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/authentication/google/#set-up-a-project-in-the-google-api-console.
- I cannot found my `Client Secret` when I declare the app is `Android` on  Google Cloud Platform Console.
- I found `Client Secret` and `Client ID` when I declare the app is `Android` on Google Cloud Platform Console.
- Nothing works.

[Error on realm.mongodb.com][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esgi5.png

Thanks so much for reading this,
I hopelessly waiting for anyone who has a solution for the same problems.

Tran Thanh Trong

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this bug too and it seems that it's being treated as a known issue by the developers.

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3116